# vector elements allocated on stack?

Tags: c++, vector, scope, storage-duration

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct A {
  int i = 0;
};

void append(vector<A>& v) {
  auto a = v.back(); // is a allocated on the stack? Will it be cleaned after append() returns?
  ++a.i;
  v.push_back(a);
}

void run() {
  vector<A> v{};
  v.push_back(A{}); // is A{} created on the stack? Will it be cleaned after run() returns?
  append(v);

  for (auto& a : v) {
    cout << a.i << endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  run();
  return 0;
}
```

The code above prints as expected:

```
0
1
```

But I have two questions:

1. is A{} created on the stack? Will it be cleaned after run() returns?
2. is a allocated on the stack? Will it be cleaned after append() returns?

Update:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct A {
  int i = 0;

  A() { cout << "+++Constructor invoked." << endl; }

  A(const A& a) { cout << "Copy constructor invoked." << endl; }

  A& operator=(const A& a) {
    cout << "Copy assignment operator invoked." << endl;
    return *this;
  };

  A(A&& a) { cout << "Move constructor invoked." << endl; }

  A& operator=(A&& a) {
    cout << "Move assignment operator invoked." << endl;
    return *this;
  }

  ~A() { cout << "---Destructor invoked." << endl; }
};

void append(vector<A>& v) {
  cout << "before v.back()" << endl;
  auto a = v.back();
  ++a.i;
  cout << "before v.push_back()" << endl;
  v.push_back(a);
  cout << "after v.push_back()" << endl;
}

void run() {
  vector<A> v{};
  v.push_back(A{});
  cout << "entering append" << endl;
  append(v);
  cout << "exited append" << endl;

  for (auto& a : v) {
    cout << a.i << endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  run();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
+++Constructor invoked.
Move constructor invoked.
---Destructor invoked.
entering append
before v.back()
Copy constructor invoked.
before v.push_back()
Copy constructor invoked.
Copy constructor invoked.
---Destructor invoked.
after v.push_back()
---Destructor invoked.
exited append
0
0 // I understand why it outputs 0 here. I omitted the actual work in my copy/move constructors overloads.
---Destructor invoked.
---Destructor invoked.
```

I updated the code in my question, adding the copy/move constructors. I found copy constructor was called 3 times in append. I understand auto a = v.back(); needs a copy, But the two other copies maybe should be avoided?

Comment: vector manages data on heap. It is possible to tweak vector and force allocation on stack, but this is rarely done.

Comment: The detail is in the answers below but basically you are worrying about things which you needn't. C++ makes sure everything is cleaned up correctly, unless you start using `new`. Anything allocated with `new` is your responsibility to clean up. Which is why you should only very rarely use `new`.

Answer (score 5):

The C++ specification doesn't actually say.

With `v.push_back(A{})` the `A{}` part creates a temporary object, which is then moved or copied into the vector, and then the temporary object is discarded.

Same with local variables, really, the "stack" is actually never mentioned by the C++ standard, it only tells how life-time should be handled. That a compiler might use a "stack" is an implementation detail.

With that said, most C++ compilers will use the "stack" to store local variables. Like for example the variable `a` in the `append` function. As for the temporary object created for `v.push_back(A{})` you need to check the generated assembly code.

For the life-times, the life-time of the temporary object `A{}` ends as soon as the `push_back` function returns. And the life-time of `a` in the `append` function ends when the `append` function returns.

Comment: Thank you so much. I updated the code in my question, adding the copy/move constructors. I found copy constructor was called 3 times in append. I understand `auto a = v.back();` needs a copy, But the two other copies maybe should be avoided?

Answer (score 2):

In this function

```
void append(vector<A>& v) {
  auto a = v.back(); // is a allocated on the stack? Will it be cleaned after append() returns?
  ++a.i;
  v.push_back(a);
}
```

the variable `a` has the automatic storage duration and is a local variable of the function. It will not be alive after exiting the function.

In this function

```
void run() {
  vector<A> v{};
  v.push_back(A{}); // is A{} created on the stack? Will it be cleaned after run() returns?
  append(v);

  for (auto& a : v) {
    cout << a.i << endl;
  }
}
```

again the variable `v` has the automatic storage duration and is a local variable of the function. When the function will finish its execution the variable will be destroyed. And all elements of the vector (that are placed in the heap) also will be destroyed due to the destructor of the vector.

Consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A {
  int i = 0;
};

int main() 
{
    std::vector<A> v;
    
    std::cout << "&v = " << &v << "\n\n";
    
    A a;
    
    std::cout << "&a = " << &a << "\n\n";
    
    v.push_back( a );
    
    std::cout << "&v = " << &v << '\n';
    std::cout << "&a = " << &a << '\n';
    std::cout << "&v[0] = " << &v[0] << "\n\n";

    ++a.i;
    
    v.push_back( a );
    
    std::cout << "&v = " << &v << '\n';
    std::cout << "&a = " << &a << '\n';
    std::cout << "&v[0] = " << &v[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << "&v[1] = " << &v[1] << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
&v = 0x7ffc27288dd0

&a = 0x7ffc27288dcc

&v = 0x7ffc27288dd0
&a = 0x7ffc27288dcc
&v[0] = 0x55725232ee80

&v = 0x7ffc27288dd0
&a = 0x7ffc27288dcc
&v[0] = 0x55725232eea0
&v[1] = 0x55725232eea4
```

As you can see the addresses of the vector v and the object a looks similarly because they are allocated in the same outer block scope of the function and have the automatic storage duration.

```
&v = 0x7ffc27288dd0
&a = 0x7ffc27288dcc
```

And they are not changed when new values are pushed on the vector.

However the addresses of the elements of the vector as for example

```
&v[0] = 0x55725232ee80

&v[0] = 0x55725232eea0
&v[1] = 0x55725232eea4
```

have a different representation and can be changed when a new elements are added to the vector because the memory for them can be dynamically reallocated.

EDIT: After you updated your question then take into account that when a new element is added to the vector the elements of the vector can be reallocated calling the copy constructor. You can use the method `reserve` to reserve enough memory to avoid its reallocation and the method `emplace_back`.

Comment: Thank you so much. So it looks like copy is done when push_back to a vector. If this is the case, should we always use vector to hold pointers instead of actual data, since copying pointers is cheaper?

Comment: @QianChen Copying pointers is cheaper but where are you going to keep the pointed objects? In any case they shall be alive and allocated some where. So it is simpler to store them in a vector Consider the demonstrative program. I defined only one local object a but using it I pushed on the vector two objects..

Comment: Should I create the actual objects by `new` so they are stored in the heap, and let the vector manage the pointers? When the actual data objects are large in size?

Comment: @QianChen The vector itself  stores objects using the operator new. Let it do the task.

Comment: I updated my question and appended some code to print copy constructor runs. Also in your example the `a` has been copied several times. I think the actual data objects were copied several times. If the data objects are large, should these copy operations be avoided?

Comment: @QianChen You can use the method emplace_back instead of push_back.

Comment: @QianChen Pay attention to that it is not a good idea to change the question after it was answered by several participants.  This will confuse readers of the question and answers.

Comment: Sorry about it. I replaced push_back with emplace_back, but it seems the same copy behavior has not changed.

Comment: @QianChen The elements can be reallocated when a new element is added. So the copy constructor is called.

Comment: So just to be clear, when you mentioned `reallocated`, it means if the element is 1MB in size, when it's reallocated, another 1MB element is copied? Is it correct?

Comment: @QianChen If a first element is pushed the vector allocates a memory for it enough large to store the object (for example 1 Mb). When a second element is pushed the vector needs to reallocate the allocated extent (because elements are store sequentially) . That is it need to allocate an extent equal to 2 Mb and copy where the already existent element before storing the new one.

Comment: I understand it. Imagine what I am doing is to get a copy of the first element, modify it, and append the modified copy to the vector. The first copy is not avoidable, so that's fine, but when appending the modified copy back to the vector, I want it somehow to do a move, instead of a copy.

Comment: @QianChen You can use std::move for an lvalue expression.

Comment: I replaced `v.push_back( a );` with `v.push_back( std::move(a) );` in your example and it seems nothing changed.

Comment: @QianChen push_back creates a copy of its argument.

Comment: I replaced it with `v.emplace_back( std::move(a) );` and nothing is changed. I wonder if `push_back` should not be used when the element is large in size?

Answer (score 1):

> is a allocated on the stack?

There is no such thing as "stack" storage in the language. `a` has automatic storage.

As far as language implementations are concerned, this typically means that the variable is probably stored in a register, or on stack, or nowhere.

> Will it be cleaned after append() returns?

Yes. Automatic variables are destroyed automatically when they go out of scope.

> is A{} created on the stack?

`A{}` is a temporary object. The language is a bit vague about the storage class of temporary objects, but it is clear about the lifetime.

> Will it be cleaned after run() returns?

In this case, the temporary object is destroyed at the end of the full expression, which is before `run` returns.

---

> vector elements allocated on stack?

No. Vector elements are created in dynamic storage.

---

> Update
>
> But the two other copies maybe should be avoided?

If your endgoal is to get a vector with two elements, you can avoid all of the copies like this:

```
std::vector<A> v(2);
```